# 'Failed to execute atob on window' unsure if it's writing the payload or the function to decode it

Tags: angularjs, authentication, passport-local, json-web-token

I've been working through this tutorial https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/creating-an-angular-service-for-authentication. I'm getting the error 'failed to execute atob on window'. I'm fairly confident the error is within the auth factory, specifically the auth.isLoggedIn function, I have console.log the response from the server and copy and pasted the token into jwt.io and it verifies like it is suppose to. So, something is wrong with the decoding function. I have tried researching [$window.atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) to understand this and debug properly but I don't understand. The jwt.sign in my userSchema didn't use any function called .btoa, so even though the tutorial says to use .atob to decode this doesn't seem right. How do I decode the token in my angular factory to save in this payload variable?

```
var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));
```

Angular App File

```
app.factory('auth', ['$http', '$window', function($http, $window){
    var auth = {};

auth.saveToken = function(token){
    $window.localStorage['rawle_news_app'] = token;
};

auth.getToken = function(){
    return $window.localStorage['rawle_news_app'];
}

auth.isLoggedIn = function(){
    var token = auth.getToken();

    if(token){
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

        return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};

auth.currentUser = function(){
    if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
        var token = auth.getToken();
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

        return payload.username;
    }
};

auth.register = function(user){
    return $http.post('/register', user).then(function(data){
        auth.saveToken(data.token);
    });
};

auth.logIn = function(user){
    return $http.post('/login', user).then(function(data){
        auth.saveToken(data.token);
    });
};

auth.logOut = function(){
    $window.localStorage.removeItem('rawle_news_app');
};

  return auth;
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post the solution in case someone else has this issue but it turns out there is nothing wrong with that decode statement but was actually in the saving the token into $window.localStorage. You can see above that I was using data instead of response, which had me believing data.token was the correct path to the token but if you console log you will see that data is also a field name. So I would have had to use data.data.token. So while I feel pretty foolish I'm going to put this here in case anyone else runs into problems with the tutorial to make sure they have something like this as their register function.

```
    auth.register = function(user){
      return $http.post('/register', user).then(function(response){
          auth.saveToken(response.data.token);
      });
    };
```